# Clipping road network that within polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, intersection, overlapping-features, vector-layer

There are two layers in the QGIS project:

- the first contains the road network for a geographical area. CRS: OGC:CRS84
- the second contains polygons that collectively cover the geographical area. CRS: EPSG:2263

I want to extract the portion of the road network within each polygon?

**Polygon layer**
[image]

**Road network layer**
[image]

My question is which tool to use to create a third layer that contains road networks for each polygon (that contains a reference to polygon attributes)

After I tried to perform an **intersection** between the two layers (road network as input layer and polygon as overlay layer), the generated layer can't display data and has the following error:

> This layer appears to have no projection specification. By default,
> this layer will now have its projection set to that of the project,
> but you may override this by selecting a different projection below.

Comment: Hi Adham, could you clarify the question? Seems like you already put the answer: "intersection" as a tag, so I'm wondering where you are stuck

Comment: Hi @underdark thanks for your reply. I have updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For vector analysis is recommended to work with all layers in the same Coordinate Reference System. What is probably happening is that there is no output for the intersection so the resulting layer is empty of both content and CRS information.

So, try to bring both layer to a mutual CRS i.e. [reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/training_manual/processing/crs.html#crss-reprojecting).